# A review/commenting django app with a rating and liking features

Tags: python, django, pinax, review

I am searching for a `Review & Rating and Vote on the Review` django app. I have searched for many, but didn't get anything like the django comment app. Basically, I require an app which can do the following:

1. Review and Rate
2. Vote the Review

I want which has the templates and the template_tags written, which I can customize as per requirements.

What I have already seen :

1. https://github.com/danawoodman/django-reviews : Here, I got what I want, but have to write the template_tags and templates from scratch.
2. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-reviews/ : Here, there is no voting feature.

Please correct me, if I am wrong anywhere and guide for the same.

Comment: Rating, reviewing and voting are three separate interactions so it's no wonder that you can't find an app that does all three. You're going to need to find three separately and bring them together, or write one that glues all three together

Comment: @Sandip: Did you find anything useful?

Comment: @Josephjun.Melettukunnel I did what Timmy suggested.